# Read a String with spaces till a new line in C

Tags: string, input, output

I am in a pickle right now. I'm having trouble taking in an input of example

1994 The Shawshank Redemption

1994 Pulp Fiction

2008 The Dark Knight

1957 12 Angry Men

I first take in the number into an integer, then I need to take in the name of the Movie into a string using a character array, however i have not been able to get this done.

here is the code atm

```
while(scanf("%d", &myear) != EOF)
{
    i = 0;

    while(scanf("%[^\n]", &ch))
    {
        title[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }

    addNode(makeData(title,myear));
}
```

The title array is arbitrarily large and the function is to add the data as a node to a linked list. right now the output I keep getting for each node is as follows

" hank Redemption"

" ion"

" Knight"

" Men"

Yes, it oddly prints a space in front of the cut-off title. I checked the variables and it adds the space in the data. (I am not printing the year as that is taken in correctly)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong type of argument passed to `scanf()` -- instead of scanning a character, try scanning to the string buffer immediately. `%[^\n]` scans an **entire string up to (but not including) the newline.** It does **not** scan only one character.

(Marginal secondary problem: I don't know from where you people are getting the idea that `scanf()` returns `EOF` at end of input, but it doesn't - you'd be better off reading the documentation instead of making incorrect assumptions.)

---

I hope you see now: `scanf()` is hard to get right. It's evil. Why not input the whole line at once then parse it using *sane* functions?

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
    int year = strtol(buf, NULL, 0);

    const char *p = strchr(buf, ' ');
    if (p != NULL) {
        char name[LINE_MAX];
        strcpy(name, p + 1); // safe because strlen(p) <= sizeof(name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Well now I have a strange thing happening. When I insert the data into a node. the strcpy() copies the name into ALL the nodes so I'm losing the name data in each node. The year of each node is staying the same, but the names keep chaning to the most recent read in

Comment: @MagicalToast This is a typical symptom of using a pointer to the very same memory buffer. Remember: arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @MagicalToast you have to allocate a separate array for each node in the list.